# How to select only the first distinct value in a column, but have blanks in that column in the other rows otherwise

Tags: mysql

Is there any way that I can turn a table like this with a query like

```
SELECT name,child from People

|----------------------|
| name    |   child    | 
| John    |   Jack     |
| John    |   Jerry    |
| Carol   |   Carol    |
| James   |   Carl     |
| James   |   Lawrence |
```

into this?

```
|----------------------|
| name    |   child    | 
| John    |   Jack     |
|         |   Jerry    |
| Carol   |   Carol    |
| James   |   Carl     |
|         |   Lawrence |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql at least:

```
SELECT 
(
    CASE WHEN child = (SELECT child FROM people AS inner_people WHERE inner_people.name = people.name ORDER BY people.name, people.child LIMIT 1)
    THEN name
    ELSE ''
    END
) AS name,
child
FROM people ORDER BY people.name, people.child;
```

Comment: Note that I added ORDER BY on the assumption that your data is intended to be grouped by name.

Comment: You should use `order by name, child` in both the query and the subquery, if you want the query to work 100% of the time and the results to be consistent.